# Saving content of map.div as PNG using widget with ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, png

I basically need to take a screen capture of the div WITHOUT all of widgets and panels on top of it. My plan is to export map scenes for eventual use in PowerPoint, so I want a 'what you see is what you get' look. The PrintTask() seem slow and the results always look like blurry garbage. Maybe I'm not calling it properly, but I haven't been able to get the extent the same as the screen or have the exact same resolution.

I've also tried building a canvas and adding all of the actual raw map tiles to it, but browser security won't allow me to export the 'dirty' canvas as a png due to Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Ideally I'll have a button in my widget called 'export' that'll generate the png and prompt the user to save it.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Web AppBuilder, add the ["Print" widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-print.htm) and configure it to export layout: "MAP_ONLY" - that will give you an image (jpg I think) of the current map - zoom level, extent, layers.